# How to deserialize a json document that does not have property names using C#?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

The Json response is like this:

```
[
    [
        1597276800000,
        "16.46340000",
        "18.34880000",
        "15.91750000",
        "17.18830000",
        "30941693.96000000",
        1597363199999,
        "527277033.75007300",
        681520,
        "15434492.74000000",
        "263241680.21583200",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        1597363200000,
        "17.17280000",
        "17.59980000",
        "16.30000000",
        "16.86580000",
        "11130678.41000000",
        1597449599999,
        "188347963.49490200",
        244865,
        "5421845.98000000",
        "91775690.92871400",
        "0"
    ]
]
```

I know the labels of these properties but they are not in the json document.
This is how the response looks in the json viewer in vs.
[image]
when I convert with json2csharp.com I get these:

```
    public class Root    {
        public List<List<object>> MyArray { get; set; } 
    }

and 

Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonResponse);
```

the compiler complains:

```
because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
```

A list of list or an array of list should work but I keep getting the same error message.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have a json with objects, simply a `list` that contains another `list of strings`.

You should deserialize like this,

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(myJsonResponse);
```

Comment: You could also deserialize it into an array of string arrays if you wanted to.

Comment: Honestly my personal preference is always List. You can deserialize to arrays as well but I find its easier to work with List<T> :)

Comment: Oh, I agree.  I was just pointing out the option.

Comment: In this case, we don't consider the types that are returned from the JSON response. This would probably lead to more casting later on.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to build a JsonConverter to be able to manipulate objects. It the data you Json response always has the same structure, I assume it would be easier to manipulate.

Here is some quick code that I put together for a custom JsonConverter:

```
public class DataObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DataObject);
    }
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        var dataObj = (existingValue as DataObject ?? new DataObject());
        dataObj.PropertyA = (long)array.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        dataObj.PropertyB = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
        dataObj.PropertyC = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
        dataObj.PropertyD = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
        dataObj.PropertyE = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(4);
        dataObj.PropertyF = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(5);
        dataObj.PropertyG = array.ElementAtOrDefault(6).ToObject<long>();
        dataObj.PropertyH = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(7);
        dataObj.PropertyI = (int)array.ElementAtOrDefault(8);
        dataObj.PropertyJ = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(9);
        dataObj.PropertyK = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(10);
        dataObj.PropertyL = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(11);
        return dataObj;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I created a dummy object to be able to extract each field with their actual types.

```
class DataObject
{
    public long PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    public string PropertyD { get; set; }
    public string PropertyE { get; set; }
    public string PropertyF { get; set; }
    public long PropertyG { get; set; }
    public string PropertyH { get; set; }
    public long PropertyI { get; set; }
    public string PropertyJ { get; set; }
    public string PropertyK { get; set; }
    public string PropertyL { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use this CustomJsonConverter as follows:

```
    //Extract Typed List
    var typedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObject>>(json, new DataObjectConverter());
```

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1**

Instead of object, you can use dynamic. It's properties and behaviors are resolved at runtime.

You can then perform casting - I've only done this before using low level unsafe context like this:

```
public class Root
{
  public dynamic[][] MyArray { get; set; }
}
// ...
fixed (byte* ptr = root.MyArray)
{
  // conversion logic
}
```

**Option 2**

It doesn't take too long to write your own JSON parser, especially if it is not intended to be generic.

Comment: Using `dynamic` for deserializing Json is ugh